Should a time index be in ascending or descending order?
Planning some new tables, I am trying to decide whether an index should be "ascending" or "descending".
The table will quite large (I imagine approx. 2000 inserts per minute, initially migrating from a different table with about 1 billion rows).
I will be using timescaledb extension for this (for partitioning by time).
This is how the table could be created:
create table "Sample"(
    "id" bigserial,
    "deviceId" int not null,
    "timestamp" timestamptz not null,
    "value" float8 not null
);
select create_hypertable('"Sample"', 'timestamp'); -- creates a desc index on "timestamp"

create index on "Sample"("deviceId", "timestamp"); -- should this be "desc"?

This is the two most common queries we'll be running (deviceId and timestamps may vary of course):
select "timestamp", "value"
from "Sample" where "deviceId"=123 and "timestamp"<'2024-01-01Z'
order by "timestamp" desc limit 1;

And
select "timestamp", "value"
from "Sample" where "deviceId"=123 and "timestamp" between '2024-01-01Z' and '2024-02-01Z'
order by "timestamp" asc;

So what I am trying to understand is in what order should the "timestamp" be? And why?
My (probably wrong) intuition tells me that the index with "timestamp" should be in ascending order, because I need to order the data by timestamp in ascending order.
But, the examples in the Timescale Documentation always index the time columns in descending order. I don't quite understand why.
What is the ideal choice of indices here?

You should definitely create the index in ascending order, unless you insert the rows in descending order.
For an index scan, it makes no difference whether it is scanned forward or backward, so for your queries the order doesn't matter.
But PostgreSQL's B-tree indexes are optimized for inserting values at the upper end, while there is no such optimization for the lower end. So if you are inserting time series data where the timestamps generally keep increasing, an ascending index is better.
Apart from this consideration, the only reason ever to create an index in descending order is if you need to support an ORDER BY condition with mixed column order, like ORDER BY a DESC, b.
